# Create new rows in Pandas from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas dataframe` in which one column (titled 'labels') contains a string of comma-separated values within a list:

```
name title labels
John III   ['ABC, DEF, GHI']
```

I would like to create new rows that separates the list at each comma, and duplicate the data for all the other columns (name, title, etc):

```
name title labels 
John III   ['ABC']
John III   ['DEF']
John III   ['GHI']
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562019/creating-new-rows-from-single-cell-strings-in-pandas-dataframe) using explode should work, but pandas is interpreting my column as an object. I tried to convert the column to a string: `df['labels'].astype(str)` but that didn't work, and this `df['labels'].apply(', '.join)` separates at the letter level rather than the whole word.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `strip()`**,** `split()` and `apply()` method :

```
df['labels']=df['labels'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',').apply(list)
```

Finally use `explode()` method:

```
df=df.explode(column='labels',ignore_index=True)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected output:

```
    name    title   labels
0   John    III     ABC
1   John    III     DEF
2   John    III     GHI
```

And if you want exact same output then make use of `apply()` method:

```
df['labels']=df['labels'].apply(lambda x:'['+str(x)+']')
```

Now if you print `df` you will get:

```
    name    title   labels
0   John    III     [ABC]
1   John    III     [DEF]
2   John    III     [GHI]
```